# MEF ExportFactory<T> - How to properly dispose in a long-running application?

Tags: c#, memory-management, mef, factory, object-lifetime

Basically, is there an easy way to dispose of the imports that are created by an `ExportFactory<T>`? The reason I ask is because the exports usually contain a reference to something that is still around, such as the EventAggregator. I don't want to run into the issue where I'm creating hundreds of these and leaving them laying around when they are not necessary.

I noticed that when I create the objects I get back a `ExportLifetimeContext<T>` which carries a Dispose with it. But, I don't want to pass back an `ExportLifetimeContext` to my ViewModels requesting copies of the ViewModel, hence I pass back the Value. (`return Factory.Single(v => v.Metadata.Name.Equals(name)).CreateExport().Value;`)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Dispose` on an `ExportLifetimeContext<T>` it will call dispose on any `NonShared` part involved in the creation of `T`. It won't dispose of any `Shared` components. This is a safe behaviour, because if the `NonShared` parts were instantiated purely to satisfy the imports for `T`, then they can safely be disposed as they won't be used by any other imports.

The only other way I think you could achieve it, would be to customise the `Dispose` method to chain the dispose call to any other member properties you import with, e.g.:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo, IDisposable
{
    [Import]
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var barDisposable = Bar as IDisposable;
        if (barDisposable != null) 
            barDisposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**But** as your type has no visibility of whether the imported instance of `IBar` is `Shared` or `NonShared` you run the risk of disposing of shared components.

I think hanging onto the instance of `ExportedLifetimeContext<T>` is the only safe way of achieving what you want.

Not sure if this helps, feels like unnecessary wrapping, but could you possibly:

```
public class ExportWrapper<T> : IDisposable
{
  private readonly ExportLifetimeContext<T> context;

  public ExportWrapper<T>(ExportLifetimeContext<T> context)
  {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public T Value 
  {
    get { return context.Value; }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    context.Dispose();
  }

  public static implicit operator T(ExportWrapper<T> wrapper)
  {
    return wrapper.Value;
  }

  public static implicit operator ExportWrapper<T>(ExportLifetimeContext<T> context)
  {
    return new ExportWrapper<T>(context);
  }
}
```

Which you could possibly:

```
[Import(typeof(IBar))]
public ExportFactory<IBar> BarFactory { get; set; }

public void DoSomethingWithBar()
{
  using (ExportWrapper<IBar> wrapper = BarFactory.CreateExport())
  {
    IBar value = wrapper;
    // Do something with IBar;
    // IBar and NonShared imports will be disposed of after this call finishes.
  }
}
```

Feels a bit dirty...

Comment: You beat me to answering my own question. I actually created an abstract `ExportFactoryController<T, TMetadata>` and a IExportFactoryController<T, TMetadata>` that keeps a dictionary of part's created and the `ExportLifetimeContext<T>`s. Then, I expose Dispose(T part) which finds the context from the dictionary and disposes of it/removes it from the dictionary. I also have a DisposeAll() which disposes all contexts stored in the dictionary and clears out the dictionary cache. Only annoying thing is my `ImportMany` is bland: `[ImportMany] IEnumerable<ExportFactory<T, TMetadata>> Factories;`